# Style scrollbar thumb on scrollbar track hover

Tags: javascript, css

I need scrollbar thumb to change color when i hover over its track. I am trying to do something like this

```
&::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:hover {
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

or

```
&::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:hover + &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: blue;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

or

```
&::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:hover ~ &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: blue;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Is this approach even possible?